# Rails generate extra <li> tags automatically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

this is the code :

```
    <ul >
            <% items.each do |item|%>
                <%= render :partial => "somepartial", :locals => { :title => item.title} %>
                test_text
            <% end %>
    </ul>
```

the partial:

```
<li><a><%= title %></a></li>
```

and the out put is :

```
<ul >
    <li><a>item1</a></li>
    <li>test_text</li>

    <li><a>item2</a></li>
    <li>test_text</li>

    <li><a>item3</a></li>
    <li>test_text</li>
</ul>
```

< li > tags around the test_text is extra. Partial and the model is not related, so do not suggest me to use collection method. When partial is rendered inside the each loop, rails does not put li tags around it, but the anything except the partial gets li tags around them.

Comment: What does your partial thingie look like?

Comment: I should not, because it is not model related partial, this is just the example of the code.

Comment: Excuse me, but what actually is the question?

Comment: If this is just an example, and not your actual code, then I'd say the problem is with your actual code. There is nothing in this example that would cause the extra li tags to show up.

Comment: Try this code and this will cause extra <li> tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is not entirely clear to me, so maybe i should refrain from answering.
But, i would propose to use [haml](http://haml-lang.com/), which gives you much cleaner views.

Your main view would become:

```
%ul
  = render :partial => "items/item", :collection => items
```

and your partial `items\_item.html.haml` would look like this

```
%li
  %a
    = item.title
```

I don't see a real link inside your `li`-item, so maybe you want something like:

```
%li
  = link_to item.title, item_path(item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<% items.each do |item|%>
  <%= render :partial => "items/item", :locals => { :title => item.title} %>
<% end %>
```

Try this:

```
<%= render :partial => "items/item", :collection => items %>
```

Comment: You'll also need to revise your `_item.html.erb` partial to refer to `item.title` rather than just `title`. If the object you are rendering is of class `Item`, then a further shortcut would be `<% render :partial items %>`

Comment: and in Rails 3, if items is an instance variable, you could refactor that even farther to `<%= render @items %>`

Comment: As I said, this partial is not specific for this model.